# Laravel - Is there any way that i can retrieve image filename with its full URL in json format without using sql concatenation

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I've written some code in Laravel to display only the images that are in mysql database, in Post table.

This is the function to display the images

```
public function index()
{
   $posts = Post::all()->pluck('image');
   return response()->json(['images' =>  $posts]);
}
```

And this is the response that i am getting which displays image filenames in JSON array

```
{
    "images": [
        "1509695371.jpg",
        "1509696465.jpg",
        "1509697249.jpg"
    ]
}
```

But i want to display them with the full URL, like this below in json format. It will be better using Laravel eloquent in that function but without using sql concatenation.

```
{
    "images": [
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1509695371.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1509696465.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8000/images/1509697249.jpg"
    ]
}
```

Any help will be much more appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be handled with a simple loop:

```
$posts = Post::all()->pluck('image');
foreach($posts AS $index => $image){
  $posts[$index] = url("/images/".$image);
}
```

The `url()` helper returns a fully-qualified URL based on your config and the path passed, so

```
url("/images/1509695371.jpg")
```

should return

```
http://localhost:8000/images/1509695371.jpg
```

Edit: To include all Data, but still format `images`, you'll need to remove the `->pluck()` function and loop `$posts`, then `$post->images`:

```
$posts = Post::all();
foreach($posts AS $post){
  foreach($post->images AS $index => $image){
    $posts->images[$index] = url("/images/".$image);
  }
}
```

Comment: This also works, Thx @Tim. What if you want to display all other data, not only images, like `$posts = Post::all();` how could you write that foreach

Comment: You'd have to remove the `->pluck()` function, then loop over `$posts`, and then `post->images`; I can do a quick edit (as that was actually my first answer, until I saw the `pluck()`)

Comment: Yes, i've removed `->pluck()` function and it works with   '$posts = Post::all();
      foreach($posts as $post){
         $post->image = url("/images/".$post->image);
      }
      return response()->json(['posts' =>  $posts]); '                              but there is a little problem of slashes inside the url, where the response comes likes this `"posts":["http:\/\/localhost:8000\/images\/1509695371-salon.jpg", "http:\/\/localhost:8000\/images\/1509695156-confidence-sized.jpg"]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-map) method on your collection:

```
public function index()
{
   $posts = Post::all()->pluck('image')->map(function($image){
        return "http://localhost:8000/images/".$image;
    });
   return response()->json(['images' =>  $posts]);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know about map method, Thx @Gacek

Comment: What if you want to display all other data, not only images, like `$posts = Post::all();` how could you return in the first place?

Comment: But you want to modify the url? Just don't pluck, and in the map function just modify the objects' images attribute and then return it.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make a AssetsService, it can have method for appending a path to an image: `assetLink('images', $image)`.

An example implementation for this:

```
public function link(string $path, string $fileName): string
{
    return sprintf(
        '%s/%s/%s',
        env('APP_URL'),
        $path,
        $fileName,
    )
}
```

Now, you need to append to several paths. Simply make a seperate method that takes an array and iterates it using the method above. Another example:

```
public function linkArray(string $path, array $files): array
{
    return array_map(function ($fileName) {
        return $this->link($path, $fileName)
    }, $files)
}
```

You can then call it like this: `$assetsService->linkArray('images', $files)`. Remember you can use Dependency Injection to get a service instantiated by laravel's container.

This gives you a reusable set of methods for file paths without making your database do unnecessary work. Services are small classes that cost very little but give you a lot of transparency. You define what you use a service for or when something is at all a service.